# ¿como puedo trabajar con horas am/pm mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

mi consulta es acerca del manejo de horas estadar colombia am/pm en el gestor de bd mysql.

es decir: yo quiero que atravez de java al usuario le aparezca la hora que quiera seleccionar en formato am/pm,
pero necesito hacer operaciones con las horas, algo parecido al manejo de horas en excel:

ejemplo: 07:58:00 a.m + 10:58:00 p.m. = 06:56:00 a.m. ó 06:58:00 a.m + 11:58:00pm + 02:00:00 p.m = 08:56:00p.m.

sumar una cierta cantidad de horas, guardar su resultado ya sea en hh:mm am o pm para luego ser mostrado en pantalla, no se como se haria esto en mysql ya que aqui el manejo de hh:mm:ss es formato de 24 hh.

con la siguiente consulta puedo obtener la suma de las horas de una misma columna, pero en formato de 24 hh. (tambien quisiera saber como sumar las hh:mm:ss en diferentes columnas misma fila.)

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(sum(TIME_TO_SEC(parada_tiemp_mp))) as totalhr_mp FROM materiaprima.
```

les agradeceria la ayuda, si quiza haya una manera ya sea por un trigger o que logica tendria que aplicar en java, gracias.

Comment: ¿De qué tipo de dato es la columna en la BD? Eso es lo fundamental. Si tienes el tipo de dato adecuado solo tienes que hacer los cálculos olvidándote del formato y al momento de presentar los datos lo formateas como quieras. Creo que te estás liando porque estás pensando en el formato antes de hacer los cálculos, para calcular fechas y horas olvida el formato.

Comment: es formato time, almacena hh:mm:ss

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si te fijas en la documentación de MySQL<sup>1</sup>, en específico en el apartado de *Funciones para fechas y tiempos*; tenemos que:

La función **`TIME_FORMAT()`**, puede recibir los siguientes parámetros:

- La columna o valor que contiene el registro de hora/o fecha a formatear
- Un segundo parámetro en forma de bandera que se puede llenar con:

  - **`%r`** el cual va a dar el formato de **`hh:mm:ss AM/PM`**

**EJEMPLO**

Yo tomo el tiempo de la función **`NOW()`** y lo formateo con **`TIME_FORMAT`**

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(NOW(), "%r") AS Tiempo;
```

Con unsa salida como esta:

```
Tiempo
07:56:56 PM
```

Entonces tus opciones son:

- Guardar los datos en el formato tradicional de 24hrs y solamente formatearlos para el momento de su salida en pantalla, cuando requieras hacer operaciones con ellos **(Recomiendo mas)**, sin tener que estar pensando en formatear según sea la conveniencia de la vista que desea imprimirlos
- Darles formato antes de almacenarlos, pasando el valor que te llega del formulario por la función antes mencionada **(Recomiendo menos)**
- <sup>1</sup>[TIME_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format)
- [Flags para formateo](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)